# Son « Tzi » ou « Dzi » prononcé dans les phrases ou entre les phrases en français

Tags: expressions, québec

J'ai trouvé que les gens au Québec produisent entre les phrases un son  comme Tzi ou Dzi.

Quand j'ai posé une question concernant ces sons, ils n'ont pas compris quel son cela pouvait être ni non plus à  quel point de leurs phrases il se trouvait.

Je sais qu'au Québec, les gens disent « tu sais » comme « tsé ». Mais il ne s'agit pas de ce son-là.

Avez-vous une idée de ce que ça veut dire ou de ce qu'ils veulent dire?

Comment: Je n'ai pas la moindre idée de ce que cela peut être ; ça ne semble pas exister en français métropolitain.

Comment: Et moi (québécois), je n'ai pas la moindre idée de ce à quoi tu fais allusion. Pourrais-tu trouver un ou deux clip youtube pour qu'on comprenne de quoi il est question?

Comment: Incroyable. Je suis allée au Québec seulement deux fois et on entends ce **tu sais** comme "tsé" partout. Et si on écoute les radios québecoises, on l'entend aussi. (ces stations s'entendent facilement au nord de l'état de NY, NH et VT, etc.). Je ne sais pas le décrire phonétiquement (trop d'effort) mais il y a sûrement des lumières ici qui peuvent le faire très facilement.

Comment: Je pense que je me suis trompé. Il me semble que c'est finalement le mot "tsé". Désolé. Il y a certains gars dans mon travail qui à chaque fois qui raconte des memoires de son adolescence il fait le son comme tzi, et à chaque fois que je les pose la question, ils savent pas de quoi je parle. Mais il se ressemble à la façon comme le mot est utilisé dans la video https://youtu.be/Ae913QSPsAk?t=133

Comment: Je viens de trouver un autre video.... je me sens un con.
https://youtu.be/GXICKEWj0W4?t=262

Comment: @MaximusDecimus C'est pas grave. Si communiquer clairement était si facile, on n'aurait pas besoin de Stackexchange :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je pense que vous parlez de l'affrication ou assibilation des sons /t/ et /d/  devant la voyelle /i/. On le voit aussi devant les sons /y/, /j/, et /ɥ/.

Vous pouvez acquérir plus d'informations sur ce sujet sur la page Web suivante: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4467